# How to convert query string to Map in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I would like to split the below query string with `;` delimiter and convert to a map. So that I can access the values iPhone, 6s Plus and 2016 by using the key.

```
def query = type=iPhone;modelName=6s Plus;year=2016
def result = query .split(';')
println result
```

I want to access the value like this - `result.getAt('type'), result.getAt('modelName')`

I tried the below approach - but it's not working as expected

```
Map<String,String> response = result.collectEntries{
        [
            it.type,
            it.modelName,
            it.year
        ]
    }
```

How can I achieve this in Groovy?

Comment: http://www.tothenew.com/blog/groovy-collectentries-to-get-a-map-from-a-collection/

Comment: @AndrewG - I tried this approach - but not working as expected

Answer (score 6):

Shortest version I know looks like this:

```groovy
def query = 'type=iPhone;modelName=6s Plus;year=2016'

def map = query.tokenize(';')*.tokenize('=').collectEntries()

println map.modelName // => 6s Plus
```

The algorithm in depth:

- the first tokenize splits input string into a list of 3 strings

  ```
  ['type=iPhone', 'modelName=6s Plus', 'year=2016']
  ```
- next we call tokenize on every element from that list to split it using `=` as a delimiter to a list of two string elements, like:

  ```
  [['type', 'iPhone'], ['modelName', '6s Plus'], ['year', '2016']]
  ```
- in the end we call `collectEntries()` - if no argument is passed it expects a list of size 2 where the first element is a key and the second element is the value of a map entry

  ```
  ['type':'iPhone', 'modelName':'6s Plus', 'year':'2016']
  ```
- finally, you get a map from the query string and you can simply access every map entry by key.

Answer (score 1):

```
def x = "type=iPhone;modelName=6s Plus;year=2016"
def m = x.split(';').collectEntries{it.split('=') as List}
println m.modelName
```